# How can i create a dashed border in flutter, and also specify the number of dash on the border

Tags: flutter

How can i create a dashed border like the one around WhatsApp status image, and also specifying the number of dashes to appear. **Using Flutter**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Currently adding a package is the easiest way to achieve this in flutter as there are only two `BorderStlyes`  `BorderStyle.solid` and `BorderStyle.none` this is the code to add the border without the dashes

```
Container(
          width: 100,// you wouldn't need this once you have a child
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            border: Border.all(
              width: 2.0,
              color: Colors.blue,
              style: BorderStyle.none,
            ),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          ),
          child: //add circle avatar,
        ),
```

[dotted_border package](https://pub.dev/packages/dotted_border)